# Inner exception(1): The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_putObject', database 'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

While i am deploying my solution in to sharepoint, it is showing:

> "Inner exception(1): The EXECUTE
>   permission was denied on the object
>   'proc_putObject', database
>   'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'".
>   Unable to deploy the solution.

Can any one give the solution....
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Share point uses the SQL Server as backend, I added my login id with admin permissions in SQL server. It is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy an SharePoint solution (wsp) write access to the SharePoint Config database is required. You have to ensure that the executing user is a Farm Administrator.

I do not recommend changing the permissions on the DB manually as suggested by "System.Exception" since this is not supported by Microsoft.

Comment: I added the user as Farm administrator in the sharepoint central administration. Still i am getting that error at the time of deploying.

Answer (score 1):

Try to activate the feature using the stsadm command

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -name thisfeaturename> -url http://thisserver/
```

Answer (score 0):

The login you are using to execute the sproc `proc_putObject` doesn't has permission to execute the sproc! For your login grant execute permission on this sproc!

Comment: Could you explain the process how can i grant the execute permission in c# code.....

Comment: @Ramesh: You cannot do that using C#, it is purely a SQL Server area